# I deployed my django app successfully without any error but when I went to the website, I saw application error, I don't understand

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed my django app successfully without any error but when I went to the website, I saw application error, I don't understand.

There's no error message on my console, I don't even know what to do or how to debug the problem. I used this

```
heroku logs --tail --app
```

-code to find the code below but i can't make any sense from it. Please I need your to help solve this problem.

```
2020-11-19T21:35:35.731246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-19T21:35:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-19T21:35:52.203195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn startingOver.wsgi --log-file`
2020-11-19T21:35:55.795727+00:00 app[web.1]: usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
2020-11-19T21:35:55.795976+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument
2020-11-19T21:35:55.876242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2020-11-19T21:35:55.926887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-19T21:36:26.125774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sover.herokuapp.com request_id=7afeb4a7-f1a4-4579-a2a2-84856e17aa89 fwd="129.205.124.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T21:36:27.625586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sover.herokuapp.com request_id=a0a558ad-fba2-40b6-8cc7-8a6fd2f25eb1 fwd="129.205.124.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T21:37:39.186291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sover.herokuapp.com request_id=afd20739-1ee9-4593-9a58-260e1bf653d7 fwd="129.205.124.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T21:37:39.848587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sover.herokuapp.com request_id=eeeaa0d2-49ef-4dbe-9062-81203f672fe5 fwd="129.205.124.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-19T21:37:46.266626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-19T21:37:51.531345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn startingOver.wsgi --log-file`
2020-11-19T21:37:54.565989+00:00 app[web.1]: usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
2020-11-19T21:37:54.566133+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument
2020-11-19T21:37:54.654523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2020-11-19T21:37:54.735076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you build a Procfile?
If you haven't make a file Procfile with the following content:

```
web: gunicorn myproject_name.wsgi
```

Comment: Yes, I added a Procfile, dj_database_url, whitenoise for static files and also included it in my settings.py middleware, I created runtime.txt, requirements.txt. I provided everything they asked for and the deployment was successful on my console without any Error. I later realized that i didn't add heroku to my allowed host which i did, see the error am getting

Comment: ```   ProgrammingError at /
relation "over_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "over_post" ```

Comment: I would recommend you to once clear your db and migrations folder and redo it

Comment: Okay, thanks Priyanshu. I will do that when I get back home